# How can i update a field with a text into a table in database?

Tags: php, mysql, session

I am trying to insert a data into a table by updating a value to it with a "text" but it does not update. I do not understand why it is not updating the table field status.

I have run the system but it seems to do no action. The ID of unique row is set to be updated

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(0);
include('includes/dbconnection.php');
//error_reporting(0);
if (strlen($_SESSION['aid']==0)) {
  header('location:logout.php');
  } else{


if(isset($_POST['submit']))
  {
    $eid=$_SESSION['uid'];
    $eid=$_GET['editid'];

    $status=$_POST['status'];;

     $query=mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE workerdetail SET status='WorkReady' WHERE ID='$eid'");
    if ($query) {
    $msg="Worker is in the WorkReady Pool";
  }
  else
    {
      $msg="Something Went Wrong. Please try again.";
    }
  }
  ?>
```

```
<a href="workpool.php?editid=<?php echo $row['ID'];?>">Update Worker to WorkReady</a>
```

This for a xampp server trying to update a field when i press the link it will update automatically and will display result in another page. So when i click on the link it should UPDATE the table automatically

Comment: you don't check for any errors, that's why you don't see  them. your query is not valid its `WHERE` not `FROM`

Comment: Enable error reporting/checking. That's why you're not getting anything back as far as errors go.

Comment: I have edited my code to the from FROM to WHERE and still have the same results .. do help please

Answer (score 0):

your sql is wrong,the right is "UPDATE workerdetail SET status='WorkReady' where ID='$eid'"

Comment: Sorry i typed it wrong here but it is WHERE however it still does not update the table
any help??

Comment: here you write post : if(isset($_POST['submit'])),but your a link is "GET",so program can't excute your update sql